# Upgrading to SSD, but keeping all programs etc. intact and usable on the current local disk

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, clean-install

I want to add a 1 TB SSD to my computer as the new local disk and do a clean Windows 10 install on it while leaving a bunch of the software, games and files on the current HDDs. I'd then delete the previous Windows files from the HDD. Would all the applications still work? Steam games would, because you can just pick the install directory, but what about programs that write data in the registry, appdata etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you answered your own question : A clean install will not include data from
the old registry, appdata etc.

I would suggest instead to clone the HDD to the SSD to begin with.
Once everything works correctly, you may delete unneeded stuff from the HDD
and move folders from the SDD to the HDD.

In some cases this would entail changing settings found inside the programs,
while for others you could replace the folder on C with a
[Symbolic Link](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/)
to the real folder on D using the
[mklink command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink).

Comment: I'd do that, but the current Windows is a bit broken (which I probably should've mentioned in the question), for example, the start menu search barely works and most ways of opening the Windows 10 settings do completely nothing. I've done 'keep personal files and apps' reinstall before and that fixed nothing.

Comment: I would check first the SMART data of the old disk to ensure that it is worth salvaging. If Windows is broken on the the new disk after the cloning, you may fix it with an [In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: The SMART is good and everything else is working properly, it's just Windows 10 being Windows 10.

Comment: So, what you're saying is that there's no way to keep the programs in my situation?

Comment: I didn't say that. I said that the easiest way is to clone the HDD with all its problems, then once the SSD has replaced the HDD, fix the problems of Windows on the SSD by doing the In-place Upgrade. This is equivalent to doing again the upgrade to Windows 10 version 1903, but you always have the HDD as backup (although other backups would be useful). A clean install of Windows can also cause problems and is not guaranteed to succeed.

Comment: I'm just thinking why would the in-place upgrade fix anything on the SSD if it didn't on the HDD.

Comment: (I should have read further up in the comments.) Yes, it probably wouldn't help. You need to decide between a clean install and fixing the problems. Both will be painful. If you decide for clean install, ensure you have all required drivers before starting. A [driver backup and restore utility](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-windows-driver-backup.htm) will be useful.